# Too many comment lines break vim's syntax highlighting

Tags: vim

I am using a verification language called 'e'. In this language the code is placed in brackets like this <'...'> . Anything outside of the brackets is considered a comment. Usually in a file, we have description of a function/file right before the brackets. I have noticed if the comment section before the brackets are too long ( greater than 100 lines) the syntax highlighting in vim breaks.

Does anyone know a solution for this problems?

Comment: Which syntax script is used? Is it a custom plugin or does it ship with Vim. Are you using the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
:syntax sync fromstart
```

to have vim redo the highlighting.  Or, you could try going to where your code starts, and do

```
:syntax sync minlines=200
```

or whatever number to have it start highlighting from the current position